# Sitemaps protocol subpages

Tags: xml, sitemap, robots.txt

I'm reading up on the Sitemaps.org protocol(http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html) so I can create my own. However one question comes to mind: How do I deal with subpages like, for example, http://www.example.com/page/subpage?

Can i just use it as a 'toplevel' `<url>` tag or do I make a `<url>` in a `<url>` tag? or do I use a `<urlset>` for each toplevel page?

And with that, can i put a *.php file who converts to a XML file in my robots.txt for Google to find. Or am I obligated to use a *.xml file?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, don't nest `url` in `url`.

Each URL gets its own `url` element. They are *all* direct childrens of the `urlset` element.

Bots don't necessarily assume (or understand) a "hierarchy" (`/page/subpage/subsub/…`) in URLs. They use it as a unique string; it doesn't matter to them if your page about soup recipes is at `/recipes/soups` or at `/soups` or at `/what-i-like` (of course, there are other reasons/use-cases why hierarchical URLs might be a good idea).

> And with that, can i put a *.php file who converts to a XML file in my robots.txt for Google to find. Or am I obligated to use a *.xml file?

It doesn't matter how you create the XML file, it only matters if it gets delivered as XML (e.g. with [Content-type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type) `application/xml`). The extension (`.xml`, `.php`, …, none at all) shouldn't matter.

Note that you can also use [RSS 2.0, Atom, or even plain text](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#otherformats) to create your sitemap.